# Draw Line in a JLabel and add as JPanel in a JFrame does not function

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

im very new in Java so sorry for any stupid question.

Here is my problem:

I just want to draw a line - if I add the `JLabel` `Myline()` directly as `label`to the `JFrame MyFrame`, then it will be showing in the resulting `JFrame`-Dialogwindow, but if I add `MyLine()` to the `JPanel` `panel` and `panel` to `MyFrame` then there is no Line.

Why?

```
package examples;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class Bsp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new MyFrame();

    }

}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private class MyLine extends JLabel {

        int width;

        public MyLine(int width) {
            this.width=width;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), 0); 
            g.dispose();


        }

    }

    public MyFrame() {

        JLabel label=new MyLine(getWidth());
        JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        panel.add(label);


        add(new JButton("A"));
        add(new JButton("B"));
        add(panel);


        pack();

        setVisible(true);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyFrame` has no preferred size until `pack()` interrogates the preferred sizes of the enclosed components. Give `MyLine` a preferred size to see the effect. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Bsp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private class MyLine extends JLabel {

        int width;

        public MyLine(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, 16);
        }

    }

    public MyFrame() {

        JLabel label = new MyLine(32);
        System.out.println(getWidth());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        panel.add(label);

        add(new JButton("A"));
        add(new JButton("B"));
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```